# Override rails route/path given the content of the URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm porting my rails app to 3.1.0 (from 2.3.8), and am refactoring. Right now I have separate models/views/controllers, for the following two pages.

[http://www.youhuntandfish.com/**fishing/fishingstories**/148-late-fall-brook-trout](http://www.youhuntandfish.com/fishing/fishingstories/148-late-fall-brook-trout)
[http://www.youhuntandfish.com/**hunting/huntingstories**/104-early-nine-pointer](http://www.youhuntandfish.com/hunting/huntingstories/104-early-nine-pointer)

'**huntingstories**' and '**fishingstories**' are really the same thing, so I want to share the models/views/controllers.

Here is the problem. In the views, I'm using helpers like 'huntingstories_path' and 'fishingstories_path'. I don't want to add a bunch of conditionals throughout the views to pick which one to use. What I want to do is write.

'stories_path'

And have some code that maps this to hunting or fishing given the '/hunting/' or '/fishing/' part of the URL.

Is there an easy way to do this in the routes file, or do I need to write view helpers? It would be even better if I could have new routes of '/fishing/stories' and 'hunting/stories', and redirect the old ones to these.

Here are the routes now.

```
scope 'fishing' do
    resources   :fishingstories
    resources   :fishingspots
end
scope 'hunting' do
    resources   :huntingstories
    resources   :huntingspots
end
```

Comment: How does your routing look now? Do you use nested routes?

Comment: I don't, but I am using the scope method. I added the story & spot routes above as I have them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of sounding self-promoting, I wrote a [blog post](http://joshsymonds.com/blog/2012/05/22/dynamic-routing-with-rails/) that details how to make this happen.

If I were in your shoes, I'd change `fishingstories` and `huntingstories` to just `stories` as well. So you'd have routes like:

http://www.youhuntandfish.com/fishing/stories/148-late-fall-brook-trout http://www.youhuntandfish.com/hunting/stories/104-early-nine-pointer

Or just remove stories entirely as it seems redundant. Either way the code will look pretty similar. In your `routes.rb`:

```
[:hunting, :fishing].each do |kind|
  resources kind.to_s.pluralize.downcase.to_sym, controller: :stories, type: kind
end
```

And in your `stories_controller.rb`:

```
before_filter :find_story

private

def find_story
  @story = params[:type].to_s.capitalize.constantize.find(params[:id]) if params[:id]
end
```

Finally, make a helper in your `application_controller.rb`:

```
helper_method :story_path, :story_url

[:url, :path].each do |part|
   define_method("story_#{part}".to_sym) do |story, options = {}|
     self.send("#{story.class.to_s.downcase}_#{part}", story, options)
   end
 end
```

Then when you type something like `story_path(@huntingstory)` Rails will a automatically convert that into `huntingstory_path(@huntingstory)`, and ditto for @fishingstory... so you can use that magical story URL helper for any kind of story.

Comment: Excellent. Too bad there isn't a rails/cleaner way to do it, but that will work. Thanks!